# Maximum Number of Equidistant Rays Guaranteed to be Perpendicular to a Given N-Dimensional Surface.

Tags: geometry

[Recently I posted a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2897758/332311) asking whether or not every closed loop is guaranteed to have an interior point from which a cross could be drawn which intersects the loop in four right angles.  The answer was no.  I wish to expand upon this: is there a closed-form equation which gives the maximum number of rays which can be spaced equidistantly from a point in the interior which guarantee all of them are perpendicular to a surface homomorphic to an n-sphere in each dimension?  For my loop question, it seems to to be two.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'am not really sure what you mean by "rays which can bespaced equidistantly from a point in the interior which guarantee all of them hit a surface homomorphic to an n-sphere in each dimension". I am having especially trouble translating/interpreting the word "bespaced". Can you give an example or expalin this some more?